# How to apply function to multiple columns

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

I would like to replace with `NaN`s values that are more than 0.99 quantile and less than 0.01 quantile in the whole dataframe.
For now I found a way of doing so with one column, so I can do it one-at-a-time, but maybe there is possibility to apply the function to all the columns without ugly for-loops?

I also tried `numpy` implementation with masking, but since the length of the result is not constant, this does not seem like a proper solution to me.

Quantile replacer for one column that works:

```
train_pl.select(
    pl.when(pl.col('B_14') > pl.col('B_14').quantile(0.99))
    .then(float("nan"))
    .otherwise(pl.col('B_14'))
)
```

And here are my numpy functions in case you need them:

```
def replace_high_quantile(arr, q = 0.99):
    mask = arr <= np.quantile(arr, q)
    return ma.masked_array(arr, ~mask).filled(np.nan)

def replace_low_quantile(arr, q = 0.01):
    mask = arr >= np.quantile(arr, q)
    return ma.masked_array(arr, ~mask).filled(np.nan)

def replace_both_quantiles(arr, low = 0.01, high = 0.99):
    mask = (arr >= np.quantile(arr, low)) & (arr <= np.quantile(arr, high)
    return ma.masked_array(arr, ~mask).filled(np.nan)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with this data:

```py
import polars as pl

train_pl = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "B_14": pl.arange(0, 101, eager=True),
        "B_15": pl.arange(0, 101, eager=True).reverse(),
        "B_16": pl.arange(0, 101, eager=True),
        "other": pl.arange(0, 101, eager=True).reverse(),
    }
)
train_pl
```

```
>>> train_pl
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 100  ┆ 0    ┆ 100   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 99   ┆ 1    ┆ 99    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 98   ┆ 2    ┆ 98    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 97   ┆ 3    ┆ 97    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97   ┆ 3    ┆ 97   ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98   ┆ 2    ┆ 98   ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99   ┆ 1    ┆ 99   ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 100  ┆ 0    ┆ 100  ┆ 0     │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

##### All columns

To replace all values above the 0.99 quantile and below the 0.01 quantile, simultaneously, and for all columns in parallel:

```py
(
    train_pl
    .with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.all() > pl.all().quantile(0.99)) |
            (pl.all() < pl.all().quantile(0.01))
        )
        .then(float("nan"))
        .otherwise(pl.all())
        .keep_name()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

##### Named columns

To restrict the operation to only some columns:

```py
only_these = ['B_14', 'B_15', 'other']
(
    train_pl
    .with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col(only_these) > pl.col(only_these).quantile(0.99)) |
            (pl.col(only_these) < pl.col(only_these).quantile(0.01))
        )
        .then(float("nan"))
        .otherwise(pl.col(only_these))
        .keep_name()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ 0    ┆ NaN   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1    ┆ 99.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2    ┆ 98.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3    ┆ 97.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97   ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98   ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99   ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ 100  ┆ NaN   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

##### Selecting by regex expression

I should also mention that you can use regex expressions in `polars.col`.  Just remember that the regex expression must start with `^` and end with `$`.  (These cannot be omitted.)

```py
regex = r"^B_.*$"
(
    train_pl
    .with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col(regex) > pl.col(regex).quantile(0.99)) |
            (pl.col(regex) < pl.col(regex).quantile(0.01))
        )
        .then(float("nan"))
        .otherwise(pl.col(regex))
        .keep_name()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ 100   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ 0     │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

##### Selecting by DataType

You can also select which columns by datatype.

```py
these_types = [pl.Int64, pl.Float64]
(
    train_pl
    .with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col(these_types) > pl.col(these_types).quantile(0.99)) |
            (pl.col(these_types) < pl.col(these_types).quantile(0.01))
        )
        .then(float("nan"))
        .otherwise(pl.col(these_types))
        .keep_name()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

##### By Exclusion

Sometimes it's easier to specify the columns that you do **not** want.  The above methods will work with [`polars.exclude`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.exclude.html), so that you can exclude columns that fit some criteria.  For example, to select all columns except columns of strings (`polars.Utf8`):

```py
these_types = [pl.Utf8]
(
    train_pl
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(
            (pl.exclude(these_types) > pl.exclude(these_types).quantile(0.99)) |
            (pl.exclude(these_types) < pl.exclude(these_types).quantile(0.01))
        )
        .then(float("nan"))
        .otherwise(pl.exclude(these_types))
        .keep_name()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 97.0 ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 98.0 ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99.0 ┆ 1.0  ┆ 99.0 ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Or for example, to exclude any column that beings with `B_`:

```py
regex = r"^B_.*$"
(
    train_pl
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(
            (pl.exclude(regex) > pl.exclude(regex).quantile(0.99)) |
            (pl.exclude(regex) < pl.exclude(regex).quantile(0.01))
        )
        .then(float("nan"))
        .otherwise(pl.exclude(regex))
        .keep_name()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (101, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ B_14 ┆ B_15 ┆ B_16 ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64   │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 100  ┆ 0    ┆ NaN   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 99   ┆ 1    ┆ 99.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 98   ┆ 2    ┆ 98.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 97   ┆ 3    ┆ 97.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...  ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 97   ┆ 3    ┆ 97   ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 98   ┆ 2    ┆ 98   ┆ 2.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 99   ┆ 1    ┆ 99   ┆ 1.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 100  ┆ 0    ┆ 100  ┆ NaN   │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Great answer. Maybe also add numeric selection via `pl.col([pl.Float32, pl.Float64])`? I can imagine wanting to exclude other types.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include selections by datatype, as well as using `polars.exclude` (which can be very handy).